# Scraping stock price from Yahoo Finance using Python & BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to **scrape** stock price from Yahoo Finance using Python and BeautifulSoup. However, I'm not able to fetch the  tag having a specific `data-reactid` attribute (See the screenshot). Please help me.

Code:

```py
def getCurrentPrice(self, stockSymbol):
    #stockSymbol is : MSFT for Microsoft
    
    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}".format(stockSymbol)
    source = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    currentPrice = soup.find('span',attrs={"data-reactid": "52"})

    print("{} : {}".format(stockSymbol, currentPrice))
```

Output:

```
MSFT : None # None because the span tag is not being found.
```

[image]

Comment: data-reactid keeps changing. Ofcourse you will find it not being found.

Comment: @ManojKumar Thanks! Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute `data-reactid` is dynamic in nature so you can't really find out the dom element using that.
Try this:

```
def getCurrentPrice(self, stockSymbol):
    #stockSymbol is : MSFT for Microsoft

    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}".format(stockSymbol)
    source = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    currentPrice = soup.find('span',attrs={"class": "Trsdu(0.3s)"})

    print("{} : {}".format(stockSymbol, currentPrice.get_text()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`yfinance`](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) package to extract quote price in 3 lines:

```py
import yfinance as yf

msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
print(msft.info["currentPrice"])

# 290.17
```

Besides changing selectors or dynamic selectors, the possible reason why you get `None` is because of not using [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) in [request headers](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) to act as a "real" user visit.

Because default `requests` `user-agent` is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and websites understand that it's most likely a script that sends a request and might block it, thus you'll receive a different HTML with some sort of an error that contains different selectors. [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/).

[Check code in online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-yahoo-finance-stock-price#main.py).

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
}

html = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT", headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

price = soup.find("fin-streamer", class_="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").text

print(price)
```

Example output

```
291.32
```